# xunit on dotnet cli project

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, .net-core

I am trying to set up xunit tests on a dotnet cli project. I realize this is very early stages of support. Right now, I am not able to restore packages. Below is my `project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002392"
    },
    "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-dev-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
      ]
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "dotnet-test-xunit"
}
```

After running `dotnet restore` I get the following errors:

```
Package xunit.assert 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package xunit.assert 2.1.0 supports:
  - dotnet (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
Package xunit.runner.reporters 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package xunit.runner.reporters 2.1.0 supports:
  - dnx451 (DNX,Version=v4.5.1)
  - dotnet (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.0-rc2-16040 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.0-rc2-16040 supports:
  - dotnet5.4 (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.4)
  - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
  - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
Package Microsoft.DiaSymReader 1.0.6 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DiaSymReader 1.0.6 supports:
  - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
  - portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 1.0.0-rc2-15996 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 1.0.0-rc2-15996 supports:
  - dotnet5.4 (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.4)
  - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

Feeds used:
    https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    https://www.myget.org/F/coreclr-xunit/api/v2
    https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-cli/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The imports that you specify cannot satisfy all the requirements. That's why you see the errors.

Try replacing them with:

```
"imports": [
    "portable-net451+win8",
    "dnxcore50"
]
```

Also, the xunit runner should be "xunit" not "dotnet-test-xunit".

See an example project here: https://github.com/aspnet/dotnet-watch/blob/46d4c6edcb374060b4e8ebf83e3ccd399f8f61ae/test/dotnet-watch.FunctionalTests/project.json